# What are the higher-resolution tracks on the ocean floor in Google Earth?

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps, the oceans are crisscrossed with what looks like slightly darker lines and patches. Zoomed in, they appear as thin tracks and whole tiles of higher-resolution imagery, with detailed seafloor relief features. The linear ones vary in resolution, with widths from 5 to about 25 km, as far as I can tell. They appear the world over but are less noticeable in the Atlantic than in the Pacific, for example.

What are those? Single-satellite passes? Subsets of some higher resolution dataset that Google acquired?

For example, https://maps.app.goo.gl/ot8XakZ7R59viMT88

[image: Somewhere between Australia and the Antarctic]

Comment: Just a guess, can it be where ships have traveled and measured depth using sonar?

Comment: I don't know for certain what bathymetric data Google uses, but many of the gridded bathymetric set must interpolate between surveyed points, leaving wide patches of smoothed/interpolated data in the un-surveyed areas.  See https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/ and https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/relief.html  -- the survey dates and quality of the data can vary tremendously.

Comment: @BERA, The narrow tracks in the picture are 3.5 km / 2 miles wide, and the wider strips around there are 12.5 km / 7.5 miles wide. I doubt a sonar can cover that much area.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lines are from ships doing sonar scanning.  The seafloor is blurry and appears smooth where it hasn't been scanned yet.  Sources: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-Google-Earth-why-are-some-areas-of-the-ocean-floor-blurred-out) (has many related questions) [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/i7wv0v/what_are_those_lines_in_the_middle_of_the_ocean/)